# NativeScript wrap/loop ListPicker

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to get a UI feel like what Apple does with their timer app, the count down timer minutes picker wraps around. Is it possible to wrap/loop like that for the ListPicker component in NativeScript?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Timepicker](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components#timepicker) is what you are looking for.

Comment: TimePicker does not deal with seconds. I'm emulating it with 3 ListPicker stacked side by side...

Comment: Actually thanks that will do the trick I can just hack a solution for the time being using TimePicker hide the hours and hide the am/pm then i have a 0-59 that rolls/wrap